# Model Form to inline using foreign key

Tags: django, list, foreign-keys

This tests my available IP addresses. It works with the standard ModelAdmin, but I need it go into the Inline. But I don't know how to get the list using the foreign key. The available IP address needs to go into the DslamSet Model, and the IP address is calculated in the IP_block Model during save.

forms.py:

```
class IP_blockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IP_blockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.ip_range:

            split_range = self.instance.ip_range.split(' ')
            ip_list_choices = zip(split_range, split_range)
        
            self.fields['ip_list'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ip_list_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = IP_block
```

This gives an error "No exception supplied":

```
class DslamSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DslamSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.ip_block.ip_range:

            split_range = self.instance.ip_block.ip_range.split(' ')
            ip_list_choices = zip(split_range, split_range)
        
            self.fields['ip_list'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ip_list_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = DslamSet
```

What am I doing wrong?

"No exception supplied" has to do with form.is_valid(). An available IP addresses is not being stored for the model choices. Because it says, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class DslamSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cleaned_data and self.instance and self.instance.ip_block and self.instance.ip_block.ip_range and not self.instance.port:
            super(DslamSetForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
            split_range = self.instance.ip_block.ip_range.split(' ')
            ip_list_choices = zip(split_range, split_range)
            self.fields['ip_address'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ip_list_choices)            
        
        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = IP_block
```